# DO Spaces on Django Cookiecutter Docker - AWS Connection Issue

Tags: django, amazon-s3, digital-ocean-spaces

I am trying to run DO Spaces on a Django/Docker. (setup via Django-Cookiecutter.)

I know all this data is good.

```
DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='DO00CBN....BATCXAE'
DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='vkmMV3Eluv8.....U1nvalkSFugkg'
DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME='my-key'
DJANGO_AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
DJANGO_AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'sgp1'

DJANGO_AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'https://my-key.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com'
```

in production.py

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env("DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env("DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env("DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
_AWS_EXPIRY = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    "CacheControl": f"max-age={_AWS_EXPIRY}, s-maxage={_AWS_EXPIRY}, must-revalidate",
}
AWS_S3_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = env.int( "DJANGO_AWS_S3_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE",
    default=100_000_000,  # 100MB)
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = env("DJANGO_AWS_S3_REGION_NAME", default=None)
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = env("DJANGO_AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN", default=None)

# aws_s3_domain = AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN or f"{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com"
aws_s3_domain = AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN or f"{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.digitaloceanspaces.com"
```

I chaged the '.s3.amazonaws.com' to '.digitaloceanspaces.com' which gives me 'https://my-zzz.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com'

But nothing i do or change makes a difference and I always get this error.

```
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://my-key.s3.sgp1.amazonaws.com/static/sass/project.scss"
```

It seems that the connection is always being overwritten by the '.s3.sgp1.amazonaws.com'

What can I do to change this setting which seems to happen in boto?

remember this is via Docker.  Can it be done via an enviorment in the production.yml? Or in the AWS Dockerfile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok, after a lot of trail and error it came down to a combinations of things.

the .production

```
DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='DO...KJ4ZY4'
DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='0AoD...F2HNPM'
DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME='bucket-name'
DJANGO_AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
DJANGO_AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'sgp1'
DJANGO_AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'appname.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com'
```

the production.py

```
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = env("DJANGO_AWS_S3_REGION_NAME", default=None)
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = env("DJANGO_AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN", default=None)
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com'
aws_s3_domain = AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN or f"{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.digitaloceanspaces.com"
```

I hope this helps and would appreciate any ideas on updating this code. IT is not my thing.

Be so easy for django-cookiecutter to make Spaces a setup option like AWS.  Hint, hint...